# Can you run Adobe Air on Windows Embedded CE 7.0?

Tags: windows, embedded, air

I cant seem to find any info on this other than:

Internet Explorer Embedded - Integrated Flash 10.1 in browser powers playback of Flash content and Flash content can be run full-screen without browser UI.

But what about AIR API's etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [packages description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee487495.aspx), it seems to me that only Flash Player ActiveX control for Internet Explorer is available. You can still integrate this control in an out-of-browser application, but the extra API for "Air mode" will not be available.